# "Cannot GET /" error - Vercel (MERN stack app)

Tags: mern, vercel

I have MERN stack app and I use Vercel for deploy my project, once deployed backend I see "Cannot GET /" error

Routes and methods in my 'index.js' file (use as a server + routes)

```
// Get Images by Category
app.get('/api/images/:category', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { category } = req.params
    const images = await Image.find({ category })
    res.json(images)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')
  }
})

// Get all Images
app.get('/api/images', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const images = await Image.find()
    res.json(images)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')
  }
})
```

My Vercel.json file:

```
    {
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [{ "src": "./index.js", "use": "@vercel/node" }],
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "/api" }]
}
```